# MVC 4 Edit Controller throwing NullReferenceException when .getJSON call is used

Tags: json, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I have a working create page which uses JavasScript to pull through various strings of data and display them on the front end.

When I have tried to implement similar code into the edit page of the same view I am met with a "NullReferenceException" - Object Reference not set to an instance of an object.

Below is the Edit method in the "ProductController", the error is thrown on the IF statement:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        using (ManagePromotion promLogic = new ManagePromotion(ref uow))
        using (ManageDistributionRule druleLogic = new ManageDistributionRule(ref uow))
        {
            Product prd = ProductLogic.GetByAndInclude(x => x.ProductID == id, new List<string>() { "AddSamplePacks" }).FirstOrDefault();
            ProductVM vm = new ProductVM(prd, (int)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["CustomerID"]);

            if (vm.Product.AddSamplePacks == null || promLogic.GetById(vm.Product.PromotionID).CustomerID != (int)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["CustomerID"])
            {
                throw new HttpException(404, "");
            }
            return View(vm);
        }

    }
```

Below also is the javascript that I have been adding into the Edit page front end, if I remove this code the page runs fine with no errors:

```
var input = "comm";
    //
    //alert("HIT");
    $.getJSON('getCat', { term: input }, function (result) {
        var ddl = $('#selectTypeCat');
        alert(result);
        //
        var length = result.length;
        ddl.empty();

        $(document.createElement('option'))
               .attr('value', 0)
               .text("-- Please Select --")
               .appendTo(ddl);

        $(document.createElement('option'))
               .attr('value', 100)
               .text("All Distribution Rules")
               .appendTo(ddl);

        $(result).each(function (jack) {
            //
            $(document.createElement('option'))
                .attr('value', result[jack])
                .text(result[jack])
                .appendTo(ddl);
        });
    });
```

The "getCat" method in the Product Controller, which works perfectly well with the create process, looks like this:

```
        public ActionResult getCat(string term)                                                             
    {                                                                                                   
        int customerId = (int)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["CustomerID"];                     
        //
        //string term = "small";                                                                        
        //
        var getCat = (from ctype in TypeLogic.GetCustomerProdIndex(customerId, term).List              
                      select new { ctype.TypeName, ctype.TypeCategoryID }).ToList();                    

        List<String> returnList = new List<string>();


        foreach (var item in getCat)                                                                    
        {                                                                                               

               returnList.Add(item.TypeName.ToString());                                                                                                                        
        }                                                                                               

        returnList = returnList.Distinct().ToList();                                       
        return Json(returnList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                                          
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: please show 'getCat' function isn't in the controller

Comment: the root cause is you try to get value in vm.Product.AddSamplePacks where the vm.Product is null (see my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realised what the problem was.

In my JavaScript I had a JSON call that looked like this:

```
$.getJSON('getDistributionNameBox', { term: input }, function (result)
```

However because it was an "Edit" page it automatically ran through the HTTP edit method whenever this request was called.

FIX:

I instead changed the call of my JSON method in the Javascript so that it explicitly called the method in question:

```
 $.getJSON('/CustomerArea/Product/getDistributionNameBox', { id: drID }, function (result)
```

This meant the edit method was no longer re-called and the dynamic JSON request could be ran multiple times in-page.

Answer (score 0):

you check `m.Product.AddSamplePacks == null` but you dont check the vm.Product is null. just Add vm.Product == null

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{
    using (ManagePromotion promLogic = new ManagePromotion(ref uow))
    using (ManageDistributionRule druleLogic = new ManageDistributionRule(ref uow))
    {
        Product prd = ProductLogic.GetByAndInclude(x => x.ProductID == id, new List<string>() { "AddSamplePacks" }).FirstOrDefault();
        ProductVM vm = new ProductVM(prd, (int)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["CustomerID"]);

        if (vm.Product == null || vm.Product.AddSamplePacks == null || promLogic.GetById(vm.Product.PromotionID).CustomerID != (int)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["CustomerID"])
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, "");
        }
        return View(vm);
    }

}
```

Comment: also it can be `promLogic.GetById(vm.Product.PromotionID).CustomerID` since `GetById(...)` might return null.

Comment: I have added the vm.product == null and now the httpexception is thrown. The getJSON request still does not happen.

Comment: I thing there is another issue, your code now not throw nullReferenceexception

Comment: @cooper1810 why return `ActionResult` when expected `JsonResult` change your return to `JsonResult`

Comment: I cant change it to JSONResult because this is the edit method that was generated by the controller. It seems to automatically be called whenever i try to do a getJSON call in my Javascript, If i changed it it would break for all the standard CRUD actions that are currently working in my system

Comment: Not the edit function, `public JsonResult getCat(string term)`

Comment: I changed it to JsonResult and it didn't make a difference, its still getting called straight back to the edit method then failing because the ID is 0 and therefore returns NULL from the lambda call.